# wireless mouse stopped working after kernel downgrade

Tags: drivers, kernel, mouse, logitech

I am using a logitech wireless mouse that use a Logitech Unifying Receiver. It was working fine when I first installed Ubuntu 18.04, however I had to downgrade the kernel from 5.x to 4.x for some software compatibility issues, so I installed 4.18.0-25. When I boot Ubuntu up with this kernel, my wireless mouse doesn't seem to work anymore. Any ideas?

Update:

Contents of `/etc/udev/rules.d/` directory:

```
~> ls -al /etc/udev/rules.d/
total 84
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec  2 12:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Nov 27 06:30 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2359 Nov 26 13:58 42-logitech-unify-permissions.rules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   451 Nov 21 15:28 51-usbblaster.rules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 58549 Dec  2 12:12 70-snap.core.rules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    78 Nov 22 16:47 99-aclpci_a10_ref.rules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    80 Dec  2 12:58 99-aclpci_de10_pro.rules
```

Contents of `43-logitech-unify-permessions.rules`:

```
~> cat /etc/udev/rules.d/42-logitech-unify-permissions.rules 
# This rule was added by Solaar.
#
# Allows non-root users to have raw access the Logitech Unifying USB Receiver
# device. For development purposes, allowing users to write to the receiver is
# potentially dangerous (e.g. perform firmware updates).

ACTION != "add", GOTO="solaar_end"
SUBSYSTEM != "hidraw", GOTO="solaar_end"

# official Unifying receivers
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c52b", GOTO="solaar_apply"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c532", GOTO="solaar_apply"

# Nano receiver, "Unifying Ready"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c52f", GOTO="solaar_apply"

# classic Nano receiver -- VX Nano mouse
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c526", GOTO="solaar_apply"

# classic Nano receiver -- MK220/MK320 mouse and keyboard combo
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c52e", GOTO="solaar_apply"

# classic? Nano receiver -- V220 wireless mouse
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c51b", GOTO="solaar_apply"

# G-Series receiver -- G-Series mouse
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c531", GOTO="solaar_apply"

# other Nano receivers known to Solaar
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c517", GOTO="solaar_apply"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c518", GOTO="solaar_apply"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c51a", GOTO="solaar_apply"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c521", GOTO="solaar_apply"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c525", GOTO="solaar_apply"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c534", GOTO="solaar_apply"

# Lightspeed receivers
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c539", GOTO="solaar_apply"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c53a", GOTO="solaar_apply"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c53f", GOTO="solaar_apply"

# Lenovo nano receiver
ATTRS{idVendor}=="17ef", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6042", GOTO="solaar_apply"


GOTO="solaar_end"

LABEL="solaar_apply"

# don't apply to the paired peripherals, just the receivers
DRIVERS=="logitech-djdevice|logitech-hidpp-device", GOTO="solaar_end"

# Allow any seated user to access the receiver.
# uaccess: modern ACL-enabled udev
# udev-acl: for Ubuntu 12.10 and older
TAG+="uaccess", TAG+="udev-acl"

# Grant members of the "aejjeh" group access to receiver (useful for SSH users)
MODE="0660", GROUP="aejjeh"

LABEL="solaar_end"
# vim: ft=udevrules
```

Output of `lsusb`:

```
~> lsusb
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 09fb:6010 Altera 
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 04d9:a06b Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 09fb:6010 Altera 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2222:0018 MacAlly 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0b05:1867 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Unplug and replug the Unifying receiver and see if that helps. Re-pair the mouse if you need to. Have you done the Unifying receiver firmware upgrade yet?

Comment: @heynnema I have tried unplugging and replugging numerous times. Also, I just did the firmware upgrade on my mac. I am not aware how I can re-pair the mouse on linux as non of the Logitech software has linux versions on their website. Please let me know if I am missing something. Also, to clarify, if I boot the 5.x kernel the mouse works, it only doesn't work if I boot the 4.x kernel.

Comment: Install `Solaar` to pair/manage Logitech devices in Ubuntu. The 18.04 repos probably have an older 0.92 version, while the 19.xx repos now have 1.0.1. Google for `solaar` if you don't find it in the repos, and you can get it there. What problems did you have with the 5.x kernel?

Comment: @heynnema I tried `Solaar`. It doesn't seem to be detecting the unifying receiver, although `lsusb` detects a Logitech device. Also, I need the 4.x kernel because I am using Intel FPGAs and their PCIe drivers don't support the 5.x kernel yet.

Comment: @heynnema I just tried booting the 5.x kernel and Solaar detected the receiver and my mouse. Not sure if it is relevant but there is a warning message next to the "Wireless Link" and a message saying _not encrypted_. Also, there are warnings for "Smooth Scrolling" and "Side Scrolling" and the tooltip says "_Read/Write operation failed_".

Comment: Open `Ubuntu Software` and let it update the firmware in the Unifying receiver.

Comment: @heynnema I am not sure what you are referring to by `Ubuntu Software`? Do you mean Ubuntu Software Center? I am running Ubuntu Mate with gnome-desktop. Anyway, I did the firmware update using `fwupdmgr` and it succeeded on the 5.x kernel. However, I still cannot detect the unifying receiver in the 4.x kernel, and `fwupdmgr get-devices` does not show the unifying receiver in the 4.x kernel.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/udev/rules.d`. Yes, `Ubuntu Software` was renamed from `Ubuntu Software Center`.

Comment: @heynnema please see above, I edited my question

Comment: Thanks for the info. There are some files in /etc/udev/rules.d that I don't recognize, like "51-usbblaster.rules", and I wonder if they're interfering with the Logitech dongle. Try unplugging all other USB devices, except for the Logitech, and see if it starts working with the 4.x kernel (you may have to reboot to test this).

Comment: @heynnema the usbblaster and the aclpci_*_ref are for the FPGA boards. I need them. I can try to unplug the jtag cables for the FPGA boards but that cannot be a long term solution because I will need to plug them in eventually. Any other ideas?

Comment: For testing purposes, go ahead and unplug all USB devices, except for the Logitech dongle, reboot with kernel 4.x, and retest the Logitech. And oh... the "not encrypted" message is because your dongle needs a firmware update.

Comment: @heynnema okay I will test that at the end of the day. Also, I was still getting the "not encrypted" message even after I did the firmware update for the dongle on the 5.x kernel.

Comment: Update:
https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360033207154-Logitech-Unifying-Receiver-Update
https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035037273

Comment: @heynnema I just rebooted without any USB devices connected other than my keyboard and the logitech receiver. Still doesn't get recognized by Solaar.

Comment: I think that I forgot to ask... what version Solaar do you have installed?

Comment: @heynnema v0.9.2

Comment: You could try downloading the 1.0.1 version (two downloads) from https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=solaar&searchon=names&suite=eoan&section=all and see if that works.